# PowerPivot field of same Row in Calculation

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Im trying to have a formula, that gets the first result of entry, for every line.

An Example Table would be like this:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Excepted Output from Formula
3           99          P 18        P 4
4           88          P 144       P 1
2           77          P 2         
2           77          P 2         
1           88          P 1         P 1
1           99          P 4         P 4
2           44          P 5         
3           22          P 7         
1           88          P 99        P 1
```

Now, on Column D it should always show the first time it finds Coulmn A = 1, and Column B the same value as the own row (99 for the first row, 88 for the second, 77 for the 3rd...), and Display the Column C of it.

I tried it with the following Formula:

```
=CALCULATE(
   FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[Column C]; TRUE());
   FILTER('Table';'Table'[Column A]=1);
   FILTER('Table';'Table'[Column B]='Table'[Column B])
)
```

Which doesnt work. No errors, but it ignores the second filter.
If i now replace the "='Table'[Column B]" with a number that it should take (99,88,77...) it shows the correct result. But since its now a static number, it shows the same Result in every line, instead of calc it always new.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[Column C], TRUE()),
  FILTER(FILTER('Table','Table'[Column A]=1),'Table'[Column B] = earlier('Table'[Column B])))
```